# Data Not inserted In Sqlite objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to insert some values in a table of database.but it is showing (NULL) on insertion

I am using This code

http://pastie.org/10929618

I have used this Link for Reference 
  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm

//Insert Method

```
-(void)SaveAction{
    BOOL success = NO;
    NSString *alertString = @"Data Insertion failed";

        success = [[DBManager getSharedInstance]saveData:@"100" username:@"byname" type:@"one2one" user_to:@"144" user_from:@"145" timestamp:@"42015"];

    if (success == NO) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                              alertString message:nil
                                                      delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

[image: Table Created]

Comment: have you check is the table is created successfully?

Comment: yes HariKrishnan , check updated question

Comment: which using to find the error first "NSLog(@"Error %s while preparing statement", sqlite3_errmsg(database));"

Comment: Showing-->>  Error 6 values for 7 columns while preparing statement

Comment: you missing one column value

Comment: "message1" your not passing  this column value

Comment: if your problem solved. can you kindly accept my answer

Comment: Thanks brother Harikirshnan

Comment: always welcome @ varinder Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the column value.

```
// you are passing the value use below method but dnt have "message1" column value
success = [[DBManager getSharedInstance]saveData:@"100" username:@"byname" type:@"one2one" user_to:@"144" user_from:@"145" timestamp:@"42015"];
// compare the below query
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into chatDetail (chat_id,username, type, message1,user_to,user_from,timestamp) values  (\"%ld\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",(long)[chat_id integerValue], username, type, user_to,user_from,timestamp];
```